# How to simplify almost equal enum extensions in Swift

Tags: ios, json, generics, swift, enums

I have extensions for about 20 enums which look like this:

```
extension CurrencyValue : JSONDecodable {
    static func create(rawValue: String) -> CurrencyValue {
        if let value = CurrencyValue(rawValue: rawValue) {
            return value
        }
        return .unknown
    }

    static func decode(j: JSONValue) -> CurrencyValue? {
        return CurrencyValue.create <^> j.value()
    }
}

extension StatusValue : JSONDecodable {
    static func create(rawValue: String) -> StatusValue {
        if let value = StatusValue(rawValue: rawValue) {
            return value
        }
        return .unknown
    }

    static func decode(j: JSONValue) -> StatusValue? {
        return StatusValue.create <^> j.value()
    }
}
```

They are almost the same except the enum type name and I have 20 of them - thats obviously very stupid. Does anybody have an idea how to reduce them to one, maybe by using generics? I have no idea at the moment.

**UPDATE**

The enums are as simple as this:

```
enum CurrencyValue : String {
    case EUR = "EUR"
    case unknown = "unknown"
}

enum StatusValue : String {
    case ok = "ok"
    case pending = "pending"
    case error = "error"
    case unknown = "unknown"
}
```

And lets assume the following:

1. Every ENUM has the .unknown case
2. I need to exchange the enum type in the extension with something generic.

There must be some trick to not implement the same extension multiple times and **just** alter the type.

**UPDATE**

As it s stated by [Gregory Higley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27779/gregory-higley) below I use the JSON lib [Argo](https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo). You can read about the operators there.

Comment: A *self-contained* example would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The essence of your question is that you want to avoid writing boilerplate code for all of these enumerations when implementing [Argo](https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo)'s `JSONDecodable`. It looks like you've also added a `create` method, which is not part of the type signature of `JSONDecodable`:

```
public protocol JSONDecodable {
  typealias DecodedType = Self
  class func decode(JSONValue) -> DecodedType?
}
```

Unfortunately this cannot be done. *Swift protocols are not mixins.* With the exception of operators, they cannot contain any code. (I really hope this gets "fixed" in a future update of Swift. Overridable default implementations for protocols would be amazing.)

You can of course simplify your implementation in a couple of ways:

1. As Tony DiPasquale suggested, get rid of `.unknown` and use optionals. (Also, you should have called this `.Unknown`. The convention for Swift enumeration values is to start them with a capital letter. Proof? Look at every enumeration Apple has done. I can't find a single example where they start with a lower case letter.)
2. By using optionals, your `create` is now just a functional alias for `init?` and can be implemented very simply.
3. As Tony suggested, create a global generic function to handle `decode`. What he did not suggest, though he may have assumed it was implied, was to use this to implement `JSONDecodable.decode`.
4. As a meta-suggestion, use Xcode's Code Snippets functionality to create a snippet to do this. Should be very quick.

At the asker's request, here's a quick implementation from a playground. I've never used Argo. In fact, I'd never heard of it until I saw this question. I answered this question simply by applying what I know about Swift to an examination of Argo's source and reasoning it out. This code is copied directly from a playground. It does not use Argo, but it uses a reasonable facsimile of the relevant parts. Ultimately, this question is **not** about Argo. It is about Swift's type system, and everything in the code below validly answers the question and proves that it is workable:

```
enum JSONValue {
    case JSONString(String)
}

protocol JSONDecodable {
    typealias DecodedType = Self
    class func decode(JSONValue) -> DecodedType?
}

protocol RawStringInitializable {
    init?(rawValue: String)
}

enum StatusValue: String, RawStringInitializable, JSONDecodable {
    case Ok = "ok"
    case Pending = "pending"
    case Error = "error"

    static func decode(j: JSONValue) -> StatusValue? {
        return decodeJSON(j)
    }
}

func decodeJSON<E: RawStringInitializable>(j: JSONValue) -> E? {
    // You can replace this with some fancy Argo operators,
    // but the effect is the same.
    switch j {
    case .JSONString(let string): return E(rawValue: string)
    default: return nil
    }
}

let j = JSONValue.JSONString("ok")
let statusValue = StatusValue.decode(j)
```

This is not pseudocode. It's copied directly from a working Xcode playground.

If you create the protocol `RawStringInitializable` and have all your enumerations implement it, you will be golden. Since your enumerations all have associated `String` raw values, they implicitly implement this interface anyway. You just have to make the declaration. The `decodeJSON` global function uses this protocol to treat all of your enumerations polymorphically.

Comment: If somebody can test if this works, please leave a comment here and I will mark this for the accepted answer. I sadly don't have more time to dig into the depths of Argon. It is undoubtedly a really cool way of JSON parsing. Keep running [Tony](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2140218/tony-dipasquale)

Comment: I did as you asked, although it's a highly unusual request on SO. It's usually the asker's responsibility to vet the answers.

Comment: Thats a pretty good answer. I would mark it as accepted twice if I could. Thank you very much for the effort. **Commet to your previous comment:** _Yes but this is a community where everybody tries to help each other. And I don't get more time to dig into this topic. Furthermore I thought it is better to have an accepted answer instead of an answer where it's unclear if it works._

Answer (score 1):

If you can provide an example of an enum as well it might be easier to see what could be improved.

Just looking at this I would say you might want to consider removing `.unknown` from all the enums and just have the optional type represent an `.unknown` value with `.None`. If you did this you could write:

```
extension StatusValue: JSONDecodable {
    static func decode(j: JSONValue) -> StatusValue? {
        return j.value() >>- { StatusValue(rawValue: $0) }
    }
}
```

No need for all the create functions now. That will cut down on a lot of the duplication.

**Edit:**

You could possibly use Generics. If you create a protocol `DecodableStringEnum` like so:

```
protocol DecodableStringEnum {
  init?(rawValue: String)
}
```

Then make all your enums conform to it. You don't have to write any more code because that init comes with raw value enums.

```
enum CreatureType: String, DecodableStringEnum {
  case Fish = "fish"
  case Cat = "cat"
}
```

Now write a global function to handle all those cases:

```
func decodeStringEnum<A: DecodableStringEnum>(key: String, j: JSONValue) -> A? {
  return j[key]?.value() >>- { A(rawValue: $0) }
}
```

Finally, in Argo you can have your creature decode function look like this:

```
static func decode(j: JSONValue) -> Creature? {
  return Creature.create
    <^> j <| "name"
    <*> decodeStringEnum("type", j)
    <*> j <| "description"
}
```

Comment: why you use $0 instead of 'j'?

Comment: but then I still have 20 extensions that look exactly the same with just another enum type.

Comment: I use $0 because I'm in a closure. The `>>-` operator will pass the non optional value into that closure and you can get at it with $0. If j.value() returns .None then `>>-` will just return .None.

Comment: You shouldn't use all those custom operators in an answer. It's VERY likely that nobody will know what they mean.

Comment: @Lance Although both questioner and answerer should have been clearer about it, it looks like they are using [Argo](https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo), which is where these operators, and types like `JSONDecodable`, come from.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else coming along, the most up to date answer is to follow: https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo/blob/td-decode-enums/Documentation/Decode-Enums.md

Essentially, for the enums

```
enum CurrencyValue : String {
    case EUR = "EUR"
    case unknown = "unknown"
}

enum StatusValue : String {
    case ok = "ok"
    case pending = "pending"
    case error = "error"
    case unknown = "unknown"
}
```

You only need to do

```
extension CurrencyValue: Decodable {}
extension StatusValue: Decodable {}
```

Also as it seems to have been pointed out repeatedly, if you just get rid of the `.Unknown` field and instead use optionals you can use the builtin support for enums as a `RawRepresentable` type.

See also: https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo/blob/master/Argo/Extensions/RawRepresentable.swift for the implementation that makes this possible.